# Displaying layouts inside DraggableGridView

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm trying to make a Grid of Image + caption pairs, that the user will be able to rearrange by drag&drop. To do this I'm using DraggableGridView - https://github.com/thquinn/DraggableGridView .

While I can display TextViews and ImageViews and rearrange them, the moment I try to connect them in one layout everything stops displaying.

So after parsing an XML with images and captions this works:

```
for(ImagePair pair : pairs){
    tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText(pair.getText());

    URL imageURL = new URL(pair.getURL());
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageURL.openConnection().getInputStream());
    imv = new ImageView(this);
    imv.setImageBitmap(bmp);

    dgv.addView(tv);
    dgv.addView(imv);
```

And it displays a grid of Texts and Images, but they are not paired - you can switch the place of text with an image etc.

When I try inserting a Layout containing an Image+ Text:

```
for(ImagePair pair : pairs){

    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageURL.openConnection().getInputStream());

    LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
    View v = li.inflate(R.layout.image, null);

    TextView txtv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.ltext);  

    txtv.setText(pair.getText());

    ImageView iv = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.limage);
    iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);

    dgv.addView(v);
```

Nothing displays. I can display any single view by doing

```
this.setContentView(v);
```

And it will display a image+caption pair properly, but trying to insert them into the grid results in a black screen, despite the grid reporting 9 children present.

The layout I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">    

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/limage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ImageView>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">  

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ltext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColorHighlight="#656565">
    </TextView>
    </TableRow>   

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue, I've opened an issue on [github](https://github.com/thquinn/DraggableGridView/issues/1)

Comment: On further testing, the views are there, I can long press on the blank screen and move them and they reorder. Just can't see them....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding one line of code in DraggableGridView.java fixes the problem. Open DraggableGridView.java and add the following line

```
getChildAt(i).measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(childSize, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(childSize, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
```

before

```
getChildAt(i).layout(xy.x, xy.y, xy.x + childSize, xy.y + childSize);
```

Hope that helps.
Found solution from another post link:[Imageview and textview not displaying in view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13699426/imageview-and-textview-not-displaying-in-view)

Comment: Posting answers that only consist of a link (or a bit of information already posted and a link) is strongly discouraged on Stack Overflow, especially if you are the author of the article. Either delete this answer and post the link as a comment instead, or edit the answer to summarize the relevant part of the article, so that it stands on its own without the link (you can keep the link in, though). Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @Dethariel for feedback.

Comment: Wow it's been so many years since I asked this question :) I hope your answer will help someone.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**

A much better version can be found [here](https://github.com/mrKlar/PagedDragDropGrid). It is based on DraggableGridView with several more features, in active development and is fairly stable.

Original Post:
I have been working on the library, I currently have it working the way you want it to using a database and I am working on moving it to an ArrayAdapter. You can find my fork [here](https://github.com/lkorth/DraggableGridView)

Comment: Thanks for doing it but I am having problems implementing it. After dragging an icon with text it jumps back to its old position. Also, I would like the GridView not to scroll. And: what is the best place to set item click listeners?

Comment: I'm actually still working on some of it, there are a few bugs with icons not swapping. If you don't want it to scroll, you can go through and delete all the methods for scrolling and remove the scroll variable everywhere it is used. As for `OnItemClickListener` I've been using a setter in DraggableGrid view to set a local variable with the listener you create in your main activity and then call it from the OnItemClick method in DraggableGridView, I'm still having trouble with it not being called though.

Comment: As always, feel free to submit pull requests, I'm hoping to clean a lot of things up still.

Comment: Yeah.. I got the icons swapping, but another bug: the just swapped icon is also displayed on the position 0.  And, after swapping any icons, the icon at the position 0 is highlighted - why and where?

Comment: sure, drop me an email addr and I will send you 2 files

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15381/discussion-between-luke-and-yar)

Comment: This whole thing is badly programmed nonsense, sorry to say this.

Comment: Anyone else having these problems -- I fixed the issue a while ago, but it's in a private repo that contains other code proprietary to my company. I'll try to separate the fixes and push them, along with the AdapterView version, eventually. Until then, check out Luke's fork.

Comment: @TomQuinn Hey Tom, any news about your fix ?