# Android Dragable GridView with Adapter

Tags: java, android, gridview, drag-and-drop, adapter

I'm looking for implementation of GridView that allows item Drag and Drop (for reordering) that supports Adapter (Views are provided by Adapter implementation). Any recommendations?

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11909011/1851478

Comment: OK. Thanks. I have looked through it earlier. Looks promising apart from the fact it is paged, not scrolled and this weird "shake" effect when moving items. Anyway it is a good starting point.

Comment: I actually use the older draggablegridview and it works fine, I think it would not be difficult to write a adapter for it.